# Backbone/Marionette trouble with displaying google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, backbone.js, marionette

I do not really know how to approach displaying a simple google maps in a div. I am new to backbone and marionette so this question bas seem trivial to anyone with experience with mvcs like backbone

Here is the my code so far in maps.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'text!scripts/templates/map.html',
    'async!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true'
], function($, _, mapTemp) {

    var MapView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({


        template: _.template( mapTemp ),

        ui:  {
            mapContainer: '#map-container' 
        },

        onRender: function() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(this.ui.mapContainer.el, mapOptions);

        }
    });

    return MapView;
});
```

my template is very simple:

```
 <div id="map-container"></div>
```

I just want my map to be displayed in the div, simple questions but with no background experience with backbone and marionette, it has become a multple-hour issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API you need an API key.
The google map api uses the form `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE`
where key = your google maps api key and sensor = true/false is if app is using GPS or a similar sensor to set location.

You are using `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true`. Which doesn't have an api key.

Alternatively, if you were using "Google Maps API for Business", the Google map api uses the form `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&sensor=true_or_false&v=3.12`
See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/#MapsJS for more information on that api.

I suspect you should use the first method, since your code seems to be similar to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld which uses the first method.

To obtain an google maps api key see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.its too bad the Google ample didn't mention the key

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in this case to fix your issue you could just obtain correct DOM selector from item view ui, not via `this.ui.mapContainer.el` but eg. `this.ui.mapContainer[0]` in google maps initializer.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(this.ui.mapContainer[0], mapOptions)
```